# Will Concurrent Dictionary holding thread unsafe collections require locks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I am declaring ConcurrentDictionary as below

[image]

My concern is, ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe, but List is not thread safe. When I will try to access this list using keys, will I have to place locks before using it? Or ConcurrentDictionary will take care of it?

Any detail, would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConcurrentDictionary` will only take care of concurrent accesses to the **dictionary**. Any code causing side effects inside the list, such as iterating it or adding values will have to come with additional locking mechanism, as the `ConcurrentDictionary` isn't responsible for that.

So yes, you will have to add a locking mechanism around the list, or simply use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<object>>
```

Comment: Thanks for precise answer